# Is there a way to access 'mod_rewrite' before 'mod_ssl'?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

Scenario:

I have 2 domains: `thinkingmonkey.me` & `thinkingmonkey.com`. Whole of the site is accessed under `https`. Bought a certificate from a CA with common name `thinkingmonkey.me`.

For `http`:

> - *www.thinkingmonkey.com*,  *thinkingmonkey.com* &  *www.thinkingmonkey.me* have a single virtual host and get redirected to *https://thinkingmonkey.me* using _mod_rewrite_ rules.
> - *thinkingmonkey.me* has its separate virtualhost.
> - Everything works fine.

Same is the case for `https`:

> - i.e. *www.thinkingmonkey.com*,  *thinkingmonkey.com* &  *www.thinkingmonkey.com* have a single virtual host and get redirected to *https://thinkingmonkey.me* using _mod_rewrite_ rules.
> - *thinkingmonkey.me* has its separate virtualhost.
>
> **The Problem**
>
> - Now, if *https://www.thinkingmonkey.com* or *https://thinkingmonkey.com* is accessed,
>
>   - **mod_ssl** acts and a TLS Handshake occurs before **mod_rewrite** does the rewrite to *https://thinkingmonkey.me*.
>   - Since the common name in the certificate is under *thinkingmonkey.me*, **This Connection is Untrusted** warning get show at the browser.
>   - Unless I complete the handshake by accepting the certificate, It will not get redirected to *thinkingmonkey.me*. Which is very annoying.

So, 
*Is there a way to access `mod_rewrite` before `mod_ssl`?*
or
*Do I have to buy a separate certificate to get rid of this?*

Comment: You shouldn't double post here and [on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9318616/372643) and then delete your question there when there are answers (although here would have been the correct place to ask in the first place anyway).

Comment: @Bruno I am well aware of the norm. Actually, I hadn't noticed the answer. I was on the page & had not refreshed it. Pardon though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, HTTPS is HTTP over TLS/SSL (see [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818)), which first establishes the SSL/TLS connection before any HTTP traffic is sent. `mod_rewrite` will always apply after the SSL/TLS connection is established.

Not doing so would actually be a security issue, since an attacker could rewrite and redirect the client before the certificate has been verified. Even if the TLS upgrade was within HTTP ([RFC 2817](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2817), which is virtually never used/supported and is not `https`), you would still want the redirection to come from a trusted entity.

The way around this is to use a certificate with multiple Subject Alternative Name (SAN) DNS entries, one for each host name, or multiple certificates (in which case you may need one IP address per certificate too, unless you're willing to use [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this.  Consider getting a [SAN certificate](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm) that includes both names.  If you get 2 certs, you will need 2 IP addresses.